# Worklight Application Center default userid/pw in the IBM SmartCloud Enterprise image?

Tags: center, ibm-mobilefirst

I am running the default instance of the Worklight Server image in the IBM SmartCloud Enterprise.
When I am trying to log into the Worklight Application Center, I am presented with a login screen that asks for my userid and password.

Where can I find the values to enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default username/password for Application Center [is demo/demo](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/c_the_application_center_console.html). Try that.
You should, of course, change/remove these if/when time comes.

Comment: According to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549232/ibm-smartcloud-enterprise-worklight-server-url-and-console-login-credentials/ this question is answered, please mark it as Answered.

Comment: Where can I reset this password. demo/demo is not working for me. Thanks.

Comment: By googling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237976/ibm-worklight-how-to-change-the-password-of-appcenteradmin