# IBM SmartCloud Enterprise Worklight Server URL and console login credentials?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am running an instance of the IBM Worklight Server in the IBM SmartCloud Enterprise: IBM Worklight Server v.5.0.0.3 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 64b BYOL.

I can log into the IBM Worklight Application Center on port 9080 without any problem.

I now want to log into the Worklight Server console itself. My understanding is that the url should be the ip address followed by port 8080 and then /worklight/console.

Two questions: the URL doesn't seem to be correct because it invariably times out.

Second question, once I have the correct login ID I also need the default userid and password.
Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: is your question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

1. The [IBM Worklight Console](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/components/console/), by default, does not come with any credentials. So there is no need for a username/password in order to access it.
2. If I am not mistaken, this "SmartCloud" version of Worklight is being run on WebSphere Liberty profile, which means that the port number is actually also `9080` and not `8080` (port 8080 is used when using the embedded Worklight Server (which runs on Jetty) in the Worklight Studio plug-in for Eclipse (Developer Edition of IBM Worklight)).

   Try `http://your-host-here:9080/worklight/console`